# react-native-tab-view width not getting 100% with two tab bars

Tags: react-native

When two custom tab bars are used in react-native-tab-view, the width is not getting 100%, ie; in the image shown, there is an extra space after the 2nd tab(On Riding). When more than 2 tabs are there, it works fine. What I expect is to get 50% width for both tab bars without any red space. [`Screenshot of tab view`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDr8O.jpg)

---------- TabView

```
<TabView
          navigationState={{index, routes}}
          renderScene={renderScene}
          onIndexChange={setIndex}
          initialLayout={{width: layout.width}}
          renderTabBar={(props) => (
            <TabBar
              {...props}
              scrollEnabled
              style={{
                borderRadius: 20,
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
              }}
              renderIndicator={() => null}
              onTabLongPress={(scene) => {
                const {route} = scene;
                props.jumpTo(route.key);
              }}
              renderTabBarItem={({route, focused, color, scene}) => {
                return (
                  <Pressable
                    onPress={() => {
                      props.jumpTo(route.key);
                    }}
                    style={[
                      route.key === props.navigationState.routes[index].key
                        ? Styles.tabBarActive
                        : Styles.tabBarInActive,
                      Styles.tabBar,
                    ]}>
                    <Text
                      style={[
                        route.key === props.navigationState.routes[index].key
                          ? Styles.activeTabText
                          : Styles.inActiveTabText,
                      ]}>
                      {route.title}
                    </Text>
                  </Pressable>
                );
              }}
            />
```

---------- Styles.js

```
tabBar: {
    paddingHorizontal: '5%',
    paddingVertical: '2%',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 1,
  },
  tabBarActive: {
    borderRadius: RFValue(25),
    backgroundColor: Colors.AppPrimaryThemeColor,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  tabBarInActive: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  activeTabText: {
    color: Colors.AppMainColor,
    fontFamily: Fonts.FONT_BOLD,
    fontSize: RFPercentage(1.8),
  },
  inActiveTabText: {
    color: Colors.AppPrimaryThemeColor,
    fontFamily: Fonts.FONT_MEDIUM,
    fontSize: RFPercentage(1.6),
  },
```

Comment: hi did you solved this issue

Comment: I am also facing same issue with two tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to scroll between the tabs?

if not, try deleting "ScrollEnabled".

```
         renderTabBar={(props) => (
            <TabBar
              {...props}
              style={{
                borderRadius: 20,
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'red',
              }}
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks for the answer.